# Remapping Keys and Mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, remapping

I have a CAD application where I need to remap some mouse and keyboard combinations.

Does anyone have any idea what I can use for this, preferably freeware if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Windows? Mac? Linux? Other?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Since there seem to be a bug with ahk itself rather than your script.

**Here are some other key remapping softwares you can try:**

http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/

http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/

http://www.softarium.com/keyremapper/

**Not free (trials):**

http://atnsoft.com/keymanager/

http://www.inchwest.com/hotkeycontrol/downloads

**The hardcore way is registry editing :**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx

**Input manipulation software using scripting (like autohotkey)**:

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

http://sikuli.org/

https://sites.google.com/site/carlkenner/glovepie

**Old post:**

First of all. Have look around in the settings for your cad application to make sure there is no way to rebind hotkeys from within the application.

A very popular macro and keybinding software is auothotkey

http://www.autohotkey.com/download/

Here is a guide for remapping keys.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm

There should definitely be a way to start both your remaping script and application for the same time...

A batch script could actually do the trick however.

Comment: The settings within the app cannot be changed unfortunately and there are lots of people who want to be able to do so.  I guess this may come in time....

I've been wrestling with AHK for sometime now and am quite frankly p***ed of with it.  No-one on the support forums will support the product and it has been a one sided conversation with myself.  The product doesn't work; at least for what I want which is a simple change of mouse/keyboard presses.

Thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: What part is it that wont work? Does ahk not work on your machine or are you not able to make desired script? Did you read the guide on remapping keys? Please post what you have so far (pastebin.com is good for scripts).

Comment: AHK itself installs and does work, it's just getting the scripting to work.... As there are a lot of trial scripts and conversation with myself it's best to take a look at this forum for a full understanding http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=92283 thanks

Comment: Thanks for these links... I'll take a look and see what I can find :)

Comment: No problem. If you solve the problem in some other way you can post an answer yourself.